# What installs the JET ODBC Driver?

Tags: asp.net, excel

I know that Excel is not a multi user app and one should not attempt to use it in a multi user web environment, but is using the JET Driver to read Excel files OK?

What installs the Jet Driver? My guess is that you get it when you install ACES or EXCEL or some other Office apps and that I wouldn't normally expect it to be found on a web server. Is this correct?

If it can be installed separately, is using this driver to read an uploaded Excel file a viable approach provided that the XLS file will only be read once when the file is uploaded into a table?

Comment: I strongly recommend reading plain csv files instead of xls. Excel formatting often causes incorrect data input when read this way.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very good C# project for reading Excel files in purely managed code with no dependencies and is safe for use in ASP.NET.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelReader.aspx

If you have significant existing code and want to stick with Jet, you can download an installer here.  Yes, it is safe for use in ASP.NET (Office automation isn't, but Jet is fine).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)